# Chainer Autoencoder

Tags: image-processing, autoencoder, chainer

I am trying to write a vanilla autoencoder for compressing 13 images. However I am getting the following error:

**ValueError:** train argument is not supported anymore. Use chainer.using_config

The shape of images is (21,28,3).

```
filelist = 'ex1.png', 'ex2.png',...11 other images
x = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in filelist])
xs = x.astype('float32')/255.

class Autoencoder(Chain):
  def __init__(self, activation=F.relu):
    super().__init__()
    with self.init_scope():
  # encoder part
      self.l1 = L.Linear(1764,800)
      self.l2 = L.Linear(800,300)
  # decoder part
      self.l3 = L.Linear(300,800)
      self.l4 = L.Linear(800,1764)
      self.activation = activation

  def forward(self,x):
      h = self.encode(x)
      x_recon = self.decode(h)
      return x_recon

  def __call__(self,x):
      x_recon = self.forward(x)
      loss = F.mean_squared_error(h, x)
      return loss

  def encode(self, x, train=True):
      h = F.dropout(self.activation(self.l1(x)), train=train)
      return self.activation(self.l2(x))

  def decode(self, h, train=True):
      h = self.activation(self.l3(h))
      return self.l4(x)

n_epoch = 5
batch_size = 2
model = Autoencoder()

optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.05).setup(model)
train_iter = iterators.SerialIterator(xs,batch_size)
valid_iter = iterators.SerialIterator(xs,batch_size)

updater = training.StandardUpdater(train_iter,optimizer)
trainer = training.Trainer(updater,(n_epoch,"epoch"),out="result")

from chainer.training import extensions
trainer.extend(extensions.Evaluator(valid_iter, model, device=gpu_id))

trainer.run()
```

Is the issue because of the number of nodes in the model or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wirte "decoder" part.

When you take `mean_squared_error` loss, the shape of `h` and `x` must be same.
AutoEncoder will encode original `x` to small space (100-dim) `h`, but after that we need to reconstruct `x'` from this `h` by adding decoder part.
Then loss can be calculated on this reconstructed `x'`.

For example, as follows (sorry i have not test it to run)

- For Chainer v2~

`train` argument is handled by [global configs](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/configuration.html), so you do not need `train` argument in dropout function.

```
class Autoencoder(Chain):
  def __init__(self, activation=F.relu):
    super().__init__()
    with self.init_scope():
      # encoder part
      self.l1 = L.Linear(1308608,500)
      self.l2 = L.Linear(500,100)
      # decoder part
      self.l3 = L.Linear(100,500)
      self.l4 = L.Linear(500,1308608)
  self.activation = activation

  def forward(self,x):
      h = self.encode(x)
      x_recon = self.decode(h)
      return x_recon

  def __call__(self,x):
      x_recon = self.forward(x)
      loss = F.mean_squared_error(h, x)
      return loss

  def encode(self, x):
      h = F.dropout(self.activation(self.l1(x)))
      return self.activation(self.l2(x))

  def decode(self, h, train=True):
      h = self.activation(self.l3(h))
      return self.l4(x)
```

- For Chainer v1

```
class Autoencoder(Chain):
  def __init__(self, activation=F.relu):
    super().__init__()
    with self.init_scope():
      # encoder part
      self.l1 = L.Linear(1308608,500)
      self.l2 = L.Linear(500,100)
      # decoder part
      self.l3 = L.Linear(100,500)
      self.l4 = L.Linear(500,1308608)
  self.activation = activation

  def forward(self,x):
      h = self.encode(x)
      x_recon = self.decode(h)
      return x_recon

  def __call__(self,x):
      x_recon = self.forward(x)
      loss = F.mean_squared_error(h, x)
      return loss

  def encode(self, x, train=True):
      h = F.dropout(self.activation(self.l1(x)), train=train)
      return self.activation(self.l2(x))

  def decode(self, h, train=True):
      h = self.activation(self.l3(h))
      return self.l4(x)
```

You can also refer official Variational Auto Encoder example for the next step:

- https://github.com/chainer/chainer/tree/master/examples/vae

Comment: thanks for pointing out the issue in the model section..and how to define activation = relu here?

Comment: Thanks again..however the original problem still persists...now I tried with a much smaller sized image..28*21 = 588 and shape (21,28,3). The error:

Comment: Can you edit your question to add your next error on the bottom of your question? (please do not delete original question, just add next error).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55844644/stacked-autoencoder is this next error?

Comment: I have updated the code and the problem statement...the link you sent is a different problem..although I would like your help in that one too if possible.

Comment: I updated my answer again. It seems you are using newer Chainer version, in that case you do not need `train` argument.